# How to return a query on only one column?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgis, postgresql-9.2

wish my query the database to return me only one column!

```
select  longitude,  latitude  
from  mytable;
```

```
longitude       latitude
42.74575        -5.096483
42.745567       -5.097
42.745          -5.098717
```

I wanted to like this:

```
-42.74575 -5.096483,   -42.745567 -5.097,   -42.745 -5.098717
```

Comment: Do you want one column and one row or one column and many rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select string_agg(longitude::text||' '||latitude::text, ',')
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is what you need    ...

```
SELECT to_char(longitude, 'FM9999') || '  ' || to_char(latitude, 'FM9999') FROM mytable
```

If you don't know how many digits there are, just estimate the maximum: `'FM999999999999999999'`